# How can I get bounding box of curved line in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to get the bounding box of the given curved line.
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pupQo.png)

Points exist as JSON

```
points: [
    { index: 1, px: 346, py: 374, cpy2: 188, cpx2: 310 },
    { index: 2, px: 405, py: 146, cpx1: 490, cpy1: 460, cpy2: 288, cpx2: 734 },
    { index: 3, px: 542, py: 117, cpx1: 683, cpy1: 115, cpy2: 115, cpx2: 883 }
  ]
```

(px, py) is point, (cpx1, cpy2) and (cpx2, cpy2) are controllers of point.
generated SVG path is:

```
<path d="M 346,374 C 310,188 490,460 405,146 C 734,288 683,115 542,117" ... ></path>
```

I just need to get the bounding box of the path.

How can I get it? thank you for any help.

Comment: `document.querySelector('path').getBoundingClientRect()` should do the trick?

Comment: Do you want an axis-aligned bounding-box, or do you want one with arbitrary orientation, such that the contained area is a minimum?

Comment: Hello, @somethinghere I should get bouding box from points, can not use getBoudingClientRect() in my case

Comment: @enhzflep, I just want to get the bonding box like this (px, py, height, width)

Comment: In SVG you may want to use the `getBBox()` method

Comment: @enxaneta, thank you. 
I was able to get bonding box using `getBBox()`.

Comment: Hi, @somethinghere. thank you for your help.
it saved me a lot of hours